# Multiple array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple problem with array, i can't solved.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/8jyUT/

Why second console.log can't display the array correctly ?

(I'm on Chrome)

Comment: it's difference when you log array or value in array.

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not display correctly'? can you actually paste your code in the question as well as the expected results + actual results.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/169101?what-stack-overflow-is-not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's logging the array  but it seems empty, because you didn't populate it numerically ( which is how arrays should be populated ). You can still access the `name` property of the array,

```
var albums = new Array();
var album = new Array();
album['name'] = 'This is War';
albums.push(album);

console.log(albums);            
console.log(albums[0].name);​
```

in JS, Any object can have properties, and arrays are objects. If you have no use for numerical ordering for the `album` nor any of the array methods, then use an object and not an array:

```
var albums = [], album = {};
album['name'] = 'Test';
albums.push(album)

console.log(albums);            
console.log(albums[0].name);​
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the value to display by adding `['name']`. I am not sure how much this helps. If you check on your current code it does show that it is an array, but you need to specific the second index for a value to display. If you are looking to do something with more properties, I would suggest an object not an array.